# Navigate questions by date (in chronological order)

Tags: support

I would very much love to scan through all the questions on UX.SE, and pick ones that interest me, and read them. There's a problem.

I can easily sort questions by votes, and make my way in, but after some posts, the order tends to change from day to day (or days) — because in the mean time, some posts may have gained a few upvotes. So, this is not really the best way to do it.

So, does anyone know a better way? Navigate questions by date, in chronological order (oldest first) perhaps? Would be really, really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want the [Newest tab in the Questions section](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest). Click the big Questions link and there's a second level tab for the Newest questions that remains in order. Technically what you see on the front page is the newest activity, not necessarily the newest questions.

Comment: I want exactly the opposite :D But it looks like that's not possible, ha!

Comment: @AahanKrish technically those posts are in reverse chronological order...if you want them *in* chronological order, select the last page to view the very earliest questions

Comment: Oops! My bad... I should've said Chronological order. What was I even thinking! Thanks Ben!